# Custom drawable for Android Action Overflow button

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm looking to create a custom style for the Action Bar in my app.  This requires making a drawable for the action overflow button, and I'm running into a little trouble going about this.  Currently I just threw together a .png, however it is clearly not sized properly and it made me realize I should probably put one together for each of the different pixel densities. Screenshot of what I have: 
[image]

So my question is a) If this is a reasonable approach, can anyone recommend what sizes I should make each image or b) is there a better approach (e.g. something with vector graphics that leaves the resizing up to android)?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Menu buttons are 32x32dp, hence the overflow should be that big. Use 9patch drawable for the system to scale properly. Take the PSD from Android Developers Guide for more.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate this icon in all sizes using the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html) Tool. Just select the "clipart" tab and they have some of the most common icons used in Android applications including the "overflow" icon.

Comment: @bkane521 Did Android Asset Studio work out for you?